# Laravel multiple models relationship return count

Tags: php, database, laravel, orm, relational-database

I have three models:

User:

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->hasMany('StoredFile', 'user_id', 'id')->with('files');
}
```

StoredFile:

```
public function files()
{
    return $this->hasMany('File', 'hash', 'user_hash');
}
```

and File models which does not have relation method

The problem:

I use the following piece of code to get projects and each project stored files:

```
$projects = $user->projects;
var_dump(json_encode($projects))
// {"project_name":"test","user_hash":"64650458b6Fhgd68ca57308222","files":[{"id":1,"name":"example.pdf"}]}
```

I can use count($projects[0]->files) to get files count

but this $projects variable need to return to client side by Response::json

```
return Response::json($project);
```

and I can't leak the files to the visitor, I want to modify the StoredFile model to return files count only

just like:

```
return $this->hasMany('File', 'hash', 'user_hash')->count();
```

but this will throw me an error:

Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on a non-object"

How can I receive the count value in relations??

please help! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relationship methods **must** return an object of type `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation`. There is nothing wrong with your `files()` function, but it is **not** a relationship, so it can't be used in your `projects()` functions.

The problem piece of code is `with('files')`, as Laravel is expecting an object of type `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation` to be returned from the `files()` function, and instead it receives an `int`.

You can manually add this value to the model though. Try adding this to your `StoredFile` model:

```php
public function fileCount() {
  return $this->hasMany('File', 'hash', 'user_hash')->count();
}
```

Change the `User` model:

```php
public function projects() {
  return $this->hasMany('StoredFile', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

Now use:

```php
$projects = $user->projects;
$project = $project->first();
$project->fileCount = $project->fileCount();
var_dump(json_encode($project));
// {..., "fileCount":"1"}
```

---

Bare in mind that the number of files is being queried from the database once everytime you ask for it, so this is not efficient if you need to return more than one project. Given that you were returning a JSON response, I assumed that this would be the case though!

Otherwise, why not just do something like this:

```php
public function files() {
  return $this->hasMany('File', 'hash', 'user_hash');
}

public function projects() {
  return $this->hasMany('StoredFile', 'user_id', 'id')->with('files');
}
```

Now use:

```php
$projects = $user->projects;
$project = $project->first();
$project->fileCount = $project->files->count();
unset($project->files);
var_dump(json_encode($project));
// {..., "fileCount":"1"}
```

Something like that should work?

Answer (score 4):

@Warren Moore is almost correct, but I just found a better solution:

```
protected $appends = array('file_count');

public function getFileCountAttribute()
{
   return $this->files->count()
}
```

this will append a `file_count` attribute to each file object

Comment: This works. However it also appears to then not only append a file_count attribute, but also all files.